# Renewing the domain name after the expiration

Tags: azure, cloud-hosting

I published a web application on Azure 2017, but the domain was expired.

It seems it is not renewable by Azure. please let me know how can I get the same domain name again. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check out their official docs here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/custom-dns-web-site-buydomains-web-app#renew-the-domain

I guess your time period for renewing it with the same domain name has expired because it can only be renewed till 18 days after the domain expiration.